# Intellij New line on current line shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a keyboard shortcut to start a new line on the currently selected line?

I.e. The current line goes down one line and the cursor is on a blank line.

There is Shift + Enter which starts a new line but on the next line. I want the current line.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> works as of 11.2.

Comment: That is the keyboard shortcut for smart statement completion. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/completing-statements.html

Comment: It's alt-option-enter for me. I don't why but my keyboard commands are all different from the official mac documentation. I didn't change it.

Answer (score 27):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> was the right shortcut for me (version 12.1.6).

Comment: This is the right answer as the question specifically states that "The current line goes down one line and the cursor is on a blank line". To start a new line below the current line use SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: I'm using on the Android Studio with `Default Keymap` and it one work fine for me. Thanks for your contribuition

Comment: documentation (windows OS) for creating new lines both below and on current line: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Adding_Deleting_and_Moving_Lines.html?keymap=primary_intellij_windows

Answer (score 21):

On mac this works for me:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↵</kbd>

Comment: documentation (for OSX) on creating new lines both on and below current line: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Adding_Deleting_and_Moving_Lines.html?keymap=secondary_intellij_osx

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one, but you can very easily create it using a macro.
In order to create the macro you can follow these steps:

1. Place the cursor on any line with code.
2. Click on menu Tools | Start Macro Recording
3. Press: Home -> Enter -> Up
4. Click on menu Tools | Stop Macro Recording
5. Test your macro using Tools | Playback Last Macro
6. You can remove any action from the macro that doesn't belong there by using Tools | Edit Macros.
7. When the macro is working fine you can assign a shortcut to it in the Settings window on the Keymap page.

Comment: If you are using version 2019.3.1 a keybind does exists, you can easily find it:
Go to preferences -> keymap. Search for 'start new line before current', then just set it if it isn't.

Answer (score -2):

Do not think anything exists in version IntelliJ 8 or 9 for that matter. Prove me wrong.